# Is translation of passport stamps necessary?

Tags: passports, languages, passport-stamps

I am applying for a visa to the UK, and the application requirement says that documents that are not in English or Welsh must be translated into English. The issuing authority of passport is indicated in my passport as a stamp, which is in Chinese, with no English translation. Since the visa application asks me to state the issuing authority of my passport, I wonder if I should have a translator translate the stamp, so that  people in charge of reviewing my application will know this stamp indicates the issuing authority. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like translation is necessary: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_passport#mediaviewer/File:Informatin_Page_of_PRC_Ordinary_Passport_(97-2_Version).jpg

Comment: @Karlson: The complication is that the issuing authority is not the Ministry of Foreign Affairs. Basically the stamp and the text above the stamp show two different authorities. The stamp looks like this one: https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5192/14343407192_5666efe86d_z.jpg

Comment: Image is not accessible for me.  I think you're looking at the wrong page.  Issuing authority is on a picture page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my post to include the picture, which I hope you can see. The stamp is actually placed on the same page as the text "The Ministry of Foreign Affairs of..."

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong page.

Comment: Sorry to not make it clear..My old passport is actually an older version, not the one shown in your link above. So the picture page actually does not indicate the issuing authority.. (mine looks somehow like this one: http://www.theepochtimes.com/news_images/2005-5-28-wenyi-passport.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the issuing authority for *all* civilian Chinese passports is the Exit & Entry Administration of the Ministry of Public Security (公安部出入境管理局), it hardly seems necessary to translate this -- if you're applying for your visa in China, they will surely already be aware of this.

But then again, if you're already getting your passport professionally translated, surely it's easy enough to translate that single phrase as well?